# How to call javascript function immediately rather than on scroll

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of javascript code here. When a hyperlink is clicked, the load_button() function is called which just sets the variable load_switch to true. I have a piece of code inside `$(window).scroll(function() {` which will fire the code when the user scrolls. So at the moment, the user clicks the hyperlink to set the variable to true, and then my load_posts function (which I omitted from the code I included to make it easier to read, see below) fires when the user scrolls. 
I would like to know how I can make the function fire without the user having to scroll first to activate it. I am editing a previously programmed function which used to be an infinite scroll (hence the function being called when the user scrolls). Here is my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
            var load_switch = false;

            function load_button(){
                load_switch = true;
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.loader').hide();
                var load = 0;

                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    if(load_switch) {
                        //load_posts function goes here
                    }

                });
            });
</script>
```

Comment: Note this is a bad approach. Instead of running the event handler always and exiting if a bool is false, get rid of that flag and add or remove the event handler instead of setting the flag to true or false.

Comment: @Oriol Please explain why adding/removing handlers is better. I think this is your opinion, not a hard fact.

Comment: @JuanMendes Because calling functions is expensive, and a `scroll` event handler will be called lots of times. And because with less variables, it's cleaner.

Comment: @Oriol Calling functions is not that expensive, it's unlikely to cause a problem. The code is often easier to maintain when you don't have to install and uninstall handlers. I'm just saying it's a design decision.

Answer (score 1):

Name your function

```
var load_switch = false;
function load_button(){
    load_switch = true;
}
// Name your function instead of defining it inline
function onScroll() {
    if(load_switch) {
        //load_posts function goes here
    }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    var load = 0;
    $(window).scroll(onScroll);
    // Call it whenever you'd like
    onScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`triggerHandler`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/):

```
$(window).triggerHandler('scroll');
```

Note this will run all event handlers. If you don't want that, you need to store the desired event handler in a variable:

```
function handleScroll() {
    //load_posts function goes here
}
function load_button(){
    $(window).on('scroll', handleScroll);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.loader').hide();
    handleScroll(); // Call it manually
});
```

Also note your approach was bad. Instead of running the event handler always and exiting if a boolean flag is false, get rid of that flag and add or remove the event handler instead of setting the flag to true or false.

Comment: The downside of this is that if there are other scroll handlers, they will also be called